# Error while parsing file: Member.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I got this problem and don't know how to handle it.

Here is my Member.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 12.07.2013 13:28:27 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="MyApp.WebApp.model.Member" table="MEMBER">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" access="field">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="NAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="surname" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="SURNAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="EMAIL" />
    </property>
    <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="USERNAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PASSWORD" />
    </property>
    <property name="result" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="RESULT" />
    </property>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

My hbm.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property  name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping resource="MyApp/WebApp/model/Member.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

the exception:

```
13:31:48,073 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."WebApp.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."WebApp.war#primary": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Error while parsing file: Member.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1255)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1247)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:76)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: post the directory structure of hbm and cfg file

Comment: Show the whole stacktrace

Comment: the hbm is in src/main/java the cfg file is in src/main/java/package/

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/224223 most probably a classpath issue having two different versions of org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Comment: Your `Member.hbm.xml` doesn't have any obvious errors, so I think it's down to directory structure, encoding problems or classpath issues.

Comment: i got one dom4j in the maven library and one in the lib folder which means i got one in the class path...but they are the same

Comment: Refer this https://community.jboss.org/thread/215758?_sscc=t

Comment: Does this mean i can remove this dependencys out of my pom??

Comment: You need to set the dependency scope as Provided